# How come gok doesn't do anything?

Tags: ubuntu, on-screen-keyboard

I am using gok under Ubuntu 9.10.

I type 'gok' in the terminal and a small window with 9 buttons comes up...
However, clicking on them does nothing.

[image]

How do I make this program work? Or is there a better on-screen-keyboard for Ubuntu?

Edit: now it does something but it shrinks to a miniscule (maybe 32x32?) window everytime I click a button and I can't read any of the button captions.

I installed gok via 'apt-get install gok'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Ubuntu comes with its own on-screen-keyboard you can start by typing

```
onboard
```

into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using desktop effects? I heard some of those on-screen keyboard programs show unexpected behaviour having compiz activated. Just give it a try and disable compiz to see if the problem is burrowed somewhere over there.

Comment: Not using Compiz. I think I solved it though anyway. See above --^